# Making Drag & Drop function to be over all website, not only a specific div part

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, drag-and-drop

I have a script which allows to drag and drop an image to a specific location.  But I want to allow it be able to be dragged and dropped all over the screen.  Not only where the div is. How can I make this? I need to create many divs or what?

My script:

```
function allowDrop(ev)
{
    ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev)
{
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev)
{
    ev.preventDefault();
    var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
    ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
}
```

My style,

```
#div1
{
    width: 350px;
    height: 70px;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
}
```

And my HTML:

```
<a href="#" id="suspect">
    <div class="image">
        <img id="drag1" src="images/suspect.png" width="160" height="140" alt="" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)"/>  
    </div>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it.  You can check here:

SCRIPT :

```
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <script>
      $( function() {
        $( "#draggable3" ).draggable();
        $( "#droppable" ).droppable({
          drop: function( event, ui ) {
            $( this )
              .addClass( "ui-state-highlight" )
              .find( "p" )
                .html( "Dropped!" );
          }
        });
      } );
      </script>
```

STYLE

```
<style>
  #draggable { width: 100px; height: 100px; padding: 0.5em; float: left; margin: 10px 10px 10px 0; }
  #droppable { width: 150px; height: 150px; padding: 0.5em; float: left; margin: 10px; }
```

HTML

```
<a href="#" id="suspect">
<div id="draggable3" class="image">
<img src="images/suspect.png" width="160" height="140" alt=""/>  
</div>
</a>
```

Comment: Not exactly resolved, but used a different approach. The original question was about `html5` `drag` feature and the answer is using `jquery` `draggable`